# SQLite count similair items based on first x number of characters

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a table of errors which look like

```
"file not configured [filename1]"
"file not configured [filename2]"
"file not configured [filename3]"
"A bomb went off!!"
```

What i want to do is get a list of occurrences of an error eg.

```
text                      occurrences   
____________________________________
file not configured..     3
a bomb went off!!         1
```

Is it possible to run queries in sqlite to check for similairity of the first x number of characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try aggregating on a certain number of first characters of each error message:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR(text, 1, 12) AS text,   -- or however long a substring you want
    COUNT(*) AS occurrences
FROM errors
GROUP BY
    SUBSTR(text, 1, 12);
```

Note that the above query is strictly not ANSI compliant, because the `GROUP BY` clause contains a function of a column.  To fix that we can just rewrite with a subquery.

Comment: Wouldn't `GROUP BY text` be ANSI compliant?

Comment: Yes but I'm not sure grouping by the full text but selecting a substring would  work.

Comment: Use an alias different from the name of the actual column and use `GROUP BY alias`